# Modificar contraseña usuario Hash, fallo si no cambio nada - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo la edición de usuario, y tomo la contraseña actual en la base de datos que está en Hash. Si cambio la contraseña no hay ningún problema, el problema viene que si no toco la contraseña y se queda la que hay, pues parece que algo raro hace por que la contraseña actual que hay ya no funciona.

En el controlador hago una condición pero parece que no está funcionando como toca:

```
if(!is_null($request->input('password'))) {
 $actAdmin->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
}
```

Esta condición normalmente lo gasto para las fotos y me funciona, si no la toco se queda la que hay.

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sustituye la validación if para usar la función `filled`

```
if($request->filled('password')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Orta , he cambiado lo que me dices, pero se sigue cambiando la contraseña tomando como referencia la que hay como `Hash`

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar algo más de código para revisar si algún otro dato modifica tu operación?